# Lualatex : how to avoid this "unnatural" \\

Tags: luatex, expansion

I have a `lua` function to withch I want to pass some extra optional `latex` code (basycally a macro with a parameter, macro can change, parameter too). I have to double backslash the name of the macro, I understand why, **but** I hope there is a tricky way to avoid this "unnatural" double backslash (latex view side speaking) ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia,xcolor}
\directlua{require("bob.lua")}


\def\Red{red}
\newcommand{\MyC}[1]{\colorbox{\Red}{#1}}

\newcommand{\TP}[1][]{%
    \directlua{Semaine("\unexpanded{#1}")}
    }

\begin{document}

% How to avoid this following double \\ ?
% if possible ...

\TP
\TP[\\MyC{works}]
\TP{\MyC{doesn't'}}
\end{document}
```

`bob.lua` file :

```
t = {}
sem = 1
t[1] = "31 Août" -- the Semaine function calculates this values
t[2] = "5 Sept"
t[3] = "A"

function Semaine (option)
tex.print ("\\rule[.5em]{0pt}{1em}\\colorbox{gray!30!white}{"
..sem.." -- "
..t[3].."}\\quad"..option.."\\hfill\\textit{"
..t[1].." -- "..t[2].."}\\par")
end
```

Comment: You could write `\TP{\MyC{ça marche !!}` instead of `\TP[\\MyC{ça marche !!}]`...

Comment: Works in my to simple example. See my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is

```
\directlua{Semaine("\unexpanded{#1}")}
```

At least it prevents, that `#1` is expanded too early. But `#1` is user contributed content, which might contain anything, including quotes, which would break the intended Lua syntax. Therefore LuaTeX provides `\luaescapestring`, which can be used as `\luatexluaescapestring` in LuaLaTeX. It automatically quotes the special characters to get a safe Lua string:

```
\directlua(Semaine("\luatexluaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}")}%
```

Then `\MyC` is kept as macro and `\\` remains the command for a new line.